# How to copy/paste data from excel to a webpage (VBA)?

Tags: html, excel, vba

So I'm trying to copy/paste data from excel into a webpage text box using VBA. However, my problem is that if I have, for example 3 or 4 rows of data copied, when pasting the values into the webpage using vba, only 1 row will be copied rather than all the rows.

Here is my code:

```
.Document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")(0).Value = ActiveCell.Value
```

Any ideas? If I take out the (0) I get an error:

> object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: First, [don't use `ActiveCell`/`.Activate`/`.Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba), second, do you perhaps mean to use `...Value = Selection.Value`?

Comment: Alright, thanks! I've tried selection.value but get an "automation error"

Comment: When you are trying to debug something, it is not a bad idea to use hardcoded values. E.g. `.Value = "Some test"` to see where the problem is and to eliminate possible reasons.

Comment: your error is because .value isn't a property of the element collection which is what you have if you remove the index e.g. 0.  Are you trying to paste data from a range (number of rows) into a single element? Or do you need a loop over rows to assign to different elements?

Comment: @QHarr, I've got a data set in excel with a filter set up and all rows of the 1st column are automatically copied. This is the data that I'd like to paste into the text box in the webpage essentially.

Answer (score 1):

This is some code of mine that works:

```
Sub FillOutInvoice(Account As Account)

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim elem As HTMLLinkElement

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate Settings.ErpAddress

    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    With ie.document
        .getElementsByClassName(Settings.InputClass)(0).innerText = Account.InvoiceNumber
        .getElementsByClassName(Settings.InputClass)(1).innerText = Day(Account.InvoiceDate)
    End With

    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Application.Wait Now + #12:00:02 AM#
    ie.Quit

End Sub
```

As you see, the needed property is `.InnerText` and not `.Value`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of sending a range of rows text to a textarea element using the clipboard

```
Option Explicit
'VBE > Tools > References:
' Microsoft Internet Controls

Public Sub InsertData()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.google.com/search?q=google+translate&rlz=1C1GCEB_enGB815GB815&oq=google+tran&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.2057j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim clipboard As Object
        Set clipboard = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")

        ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A3").Copy

        With clipboard
            .GetFromClipboard
            ie.document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")(1).innerText = .GetText
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Contents of Range("A1:A3")**

[image]